# using autocomplete to bring data from DB with angularjs material

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

I want to use autocomplete to bring data from DB
in my application I have more than 150 companies and the user must select one of them so I want to use autocomplete
so when the user write 2 letters in the text field I want to display the companies that start with these 2 leters. 
I used the example floating label from here https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete and modified it just like that

```
                             * Search for states... use $timeout to simulate
                             * remote dataservice call.
                             */
                             function querySearch (query) {
                              var results = createFilterFor(query);
                              var deferred = $q.defer();
                              $timeout(function () { deferred.resolve( results ); }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
                              return deferred.promise;
                            }



                             * filterCompany function return the company that start with cmompanycode
                             */
                             function createFilterFor (companyCode) {
                                 service.filterCompany(companyCode).then(function (response) {
                                     return response.data.companies;

                                 });
                             }
```

and this is the html

```
<div class="col-sm-2" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.company.$dirty && form.company.$error.required }">
            <md-input-container class="md-block">
                <md-autocomplete flex="" required="" md-input-name="autocompleteField" md-input-minlength="2" md-input-maxlength="18" md-no-cache="ul.noCache" md-selected-item="ul.selectedItem" md-search-text="ul.searchText" md-items="item in ul.querySearch(ul.searchText)" md-item-text="item.display" md-floating-label="Favorite state">
                    <md-item-template>
                        <span md-highlight-text="ul.searchText">{{item.display}}</span>
                    </md-item-template>
                </md-autocomplete>
            </md-input-container>
        </div>
```

but when I run the code I get

```
angular.js:12520 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at W (angular-material.min.js:12)
    at j (angular-material.min.js:12)
    at o (angular-material.min.js:12)
    at processQueue (angular.js:14792)
    at angular.js:14808
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16052)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15870)
    at angular.js:16091
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5552)
    at angular.js:5829
```

this is my service

```
function filterCompany(companyCode){
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                  // simulate api call with $timeout
                     return $timeout(function () {
                        var encodeString = 'companyCode='+companyCode
                            return $http({
                                  url: './getCompaniesAutoComplete',
                                  method: "POST",
                                  data: encodeString,
                                  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                              }).success(function (response) {
                                  response.message = 'getUser done Successfully';
                              }).error(function (response){
                                 response.message = 'Error during getUser operation';
                              });
                              deferred.resolve({ success: true });
                      }, 1000);
                     return deferred.promise;
                }
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if your service is really returning data?

Comment: yes it is returning data

Comment: java code return data  and  function createFilterFor in the controller returns data but the error is appear before executing this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably going through some CTRL+C CTRL+V misunderstanding and mixing up mock `$timeout` code from documentation with your own code.

Autocomplete accepts promise which gets resolved with array of items or simply the array. The promise never gets resolved with any response or data, because it gets resolved here in `filterCompany`:

 `deferred.resolve({ success: true });`

Get rid of the timeouts and manual deffers. Do something like:

```
function filterCompany(companyCode) {
    var encodeString = 'companyCode='+companyCode
    return $http({
        url: './getCompaniesAutoComplete',
        method: "POST",
        data: encodeString,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    });
}
```

In your controller then:

```
function querySearch(companyCode) {
    return service.filterCompany(companyCode)
                .then(function (response) {
                     return response.data.companies;
                });
}
```

This is all you need.

Comment: hey .. Kvetis i have a same doubt.Now i read your answer, would you plz help me with a plunker example..

Comment: If you have a specific problem, you can open up a new question with a plnkr example what you want to make to work.